# Is it possible to do inlining in C# which optimizes string concatenation?

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor, inlining

Assume you have such C# code:

```
const string ABC = "ABC";
const string XYZ = "XYZ";

var result = ABC + ":" + XYZ;
```

Such code is optimized by the compiler, so you have one constant string literal "ABC:XYZ" in the result variable, instead of doing the actual concatenation of 3 strings at runtime.

Now I want to introduce a helper function that will hide that concatenation from users (to make the code more robust and less error prone):

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    static string Combine(string first, string second) => first + ":" + second;

const string ABC = "ABC";
const string XYZ = "XYZ";

var result = Combine(ABC, XYZ);
```

In this case I see that the method is actually inlined in the calling method, but in the disassembly I can clearly see that it calls the `string.Concat(string a, string b, string c)` at runtime, instead of having one constant string literal "ABC:XYZ".

I understand that there is a balance between speed and quality during compilation, but is there any trick to have the `Combine` method work as a C++ macro to avoid redundant string concatenations at runtime?

P.S. introducing static readonly strings that get computed once is not an answer to the question.

Comment: why can't you just use the string.Concat() function.?

Comment: because it's slow, I need performance

Comment: running it based on your example from my end is not slow at wll .. what about string.Join() method then..

Comment: @MethodMan, count number of instructions and memory allocated in both cases

Comment: I run the following in a Console app regards less if it's in a method or not and it performs so fast it's not even funny 
`string ABC = "ABC";
  string XYZ = "XYZ";
  string conStr = ":";
  var resultConCat = string.Concat(ABC, conStr, XYZ);`

Comment: I asked a concrete question if is it's possible or not to do, but instead you are trying to convince me that it does not matter. If it does not matter, I wouldn't post a question in first place.

Answer (score 3):

It is useful to understand the `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining` hint and what it is about / what it is useful for.

My understanding is that method inlining (whether it's hinted / wished by the programmer to be done aggressively or not) -- is all about *call sites* (i.e., in your case, about "by whom/where" your Combine is called), but not about what otherwise constitutes the (possibly inlined) method's body.

In other words, when you refactored your expression

```
... ABC + ":" + XYZ ...
```

(which is exactly the "perfect" / nominal candidate for constant folding optimization, obviously)

into

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
static string Combine(string first, string second) => first + ":" + second
```

and then

(at a call site)

```
... Combine(ABC, XYZ) ...
```

you really "told" something quite different to the compiler:

"I want a static method that takes two strings and returns a third, I want to call it at this call site right here, oh, and please try to inline that for me."

Because in your case Combine is clearly a pure, non-recursive function that does nothing with the call stack that cannot be rewritten "in place" wherever it is invoked with actual arguments (be those constants or not), it is indeed feasible to inline its invocation -- but that still says nothing about what other, additional optimizations could be possible *over* the Combine method's *body* itself, here equivalent to (after lambda desugaring)

```
return first + ":" + second;
```

(and thus compiled as

```
return string.Concat(first, second);
```

as you noticed)

After all, what if other parts of your code have a logic that depends on reflecting (thru System.Reflection's functionality) over it? It still needs to be declared as a member somewhere and to have a body attached to it, no? (again, whether or not it can, "as a bonus", be inlined here or there, etc)

From there, "a body attached to it" implies there must be one, and exactly one, expressed in CIL/MSIL, etc.

That's how I see this [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] on your Combine method as a mere hint for, "hey, please, let's avoid the sole, silly stack frame here and there to call Combine, whenever we can." -- and nothing beyond that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand either why it's downvoted - it's a legit compiler optimization question posted according with StackOverflow guidelines. I'm just curious if it possible to force compiler to optimize the caller's body with injected method(s) body(ies). I assume the answer is no, but hope that a guru of a dot net compiler comes across this question and can confirm such assumption.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this using compile-time weaving.  The idea here is that you would find all the call sites for your method (don't inline them!) and replace them at compile time with ldtoken opcodes with the concatenated string as the operand.

These tools will be useful in achieving your objective.

•PostSharp
•Aspect.NET. Relies on Phoenix.
•AspectDNG. Relies on Cecil.
• ComposeStar /  StarLight
• Gripper Loom.NET
•Phx.Morph/Wicca. Relies on Phoenix.